# Amazon AWS Multiple Elastic IP Squid Proxy Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have an Amazon AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.0.4 server using squid proxy.

I have managed to configure the the default IP address as a proxy without an issue.
The problem is when I attach additional elastic IP addresses I cannot get them to work.
So I have an EC2 server with 2x network interfaces, both with a private and public IP addresses (one with the default public IP and another with the elastic IP). Both network interfaces are attached to the same security group with my desired proxy ports open.
Within my EC2 instance, I can see eth0 and eth1 by performing an ifconfig. 
I cannot even SSH in on the elastic IP.

Within Ubuntu, I can route print and it shows eth0 and eth1 using the same default gateway. I assume this is not correct?

I think I might be missing some routing settings configured in the VPC section.

This is an example of my squid config file.

```
acl tasty3128 myportname 3128 src 172.X.X.X/24
http_access allow tasty3128
tcp_outgoing_address 67.xxx.108.128 tasty3128
acl tasty3129 myportname 3129 src 172.X.X.X/24
http_access allow tasty3129
tcp_outgoing_address 67.xxx.108.79 tasty3129
```

thankyou

Comment: The security groups are based on Instance level and as well NIC card level. So you need to check the SGs for eth1 and give access according to it

Comment: The instance is set to the correct security group.
And both NIC cards (within the Network Interfaces tab) are in the correct security group.  
Any other suggestions?